# how can i change default xdg-viewer on chromium

Tags: linux, vnc, xdg

I want to change my external default viewer not to be xdg, i need it too be VNC... I tried on chrome/settings but found nothing. im using ubuntu 14.04(ZorinOS[image]

Answer (score 0):

xdg-open isn't a viewer. It's the way the OS associates your content with your preferred app. (From the manual: "xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application.") Go ahead and let it open your file, then pick your preferred application when it asks you what to use. It'll remember it from then on.

You can change it with either a "Preferred Applications" control panel, or by opening the Properties pane of the file itself and choosing "Open With...", IIRC.

Comment: The problem is when i press open with xdg it doesn't open anything...

Comment: OK, then you need to set up your associations. Not sure how Ubuntu handles that, sorry. But good luck!